# C# Batch file output problems

Tags: c#, batch-file

I have been working on a manager application for a Minecraft server, when I run my program, the console shows and disappears, if I run it manually, it runs without and problems.
Batch file code:

```
java -Xmx1024M -jar craftbukkit-1.7.2-R0.3.jar -o false
```

My full code (MessageBoxes are in Polish, becouse im from Poland, but later i will add support for other languages):

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Process server;

        private Boolean runServer()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(textBox2.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Brak określonej ścieżki dostępu! (" + textBox2.Text + ")", "Błąd", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
            }

            Process process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = textBox2.Text,
                    //Arguments = textBox3.Text,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = false,
                }
            };

            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(server_outputDataReceived);
            process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(server_outputDataReceived);
            server = process;

            if (process.Start())
                return true;
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nie można włączyć serwera!", "Błąd", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private String ReadFile(String filename, int line)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);

            for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
            {
                reader.ReadLine();
            }

            return reader.ReadLine();
        }

        private void ReloadOPs()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(textBox1.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sciezka dostępu do pliku z listą graczy posiadających OP nie istnieje! (" + textBox1.Text + ")", "Błąd", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPageOptions;
                textBox1.SelectAll();
                return;
            }

            String line = ReadFile(textBox1.Text, 0);
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 1; i < File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text).Length; i++)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ReadFile(textBox1.Text, i)))
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
                    line = ReadFile(textBox1.Text, i);
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Lista graczy z OP, została odświeżona.");
        }

        // OPs combobox (OPs)
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            groupBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            groupBox1.Visible = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + @"\ops.txt";
            ReloadOPs();
        }

        // Reload OPs button (OPs)
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReloadOPs();
        }


        // Save button (Options)
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void server_outputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            addConsoleMessage(e.Data.ToString(), true);
        }

        // Run server button (Menu)
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!runServer())
                return;

            server.BeginOutputReadLine();
            button6.Enabled = true;
        }

        // Stop server button (Menu)
        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!server.HasExited)
                server.Kill();
            button6.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void addConsoleMessage(String message, Boolean refresh)
        {
            listBox1.Items.Add(message);
            if (refresh)
                listBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

My problem is that program crashes becouse InvaildOperationException was unhandled (listBox1.Items.Add(message) in addConsoleMessage).
External error information: Invalid operation between threads: the control 'listBox1' is accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created.

Comment: Set breakpoint and debug `addConsoleMessage` function and check what actually causing it to throw exception.

Comment: It throws InvalidOperationException becouse, (as it says) "Invalid operation between threads: the control 'listBox1' is accessed from a thread other than the thread it was created."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot update UI form background thread. Try this

**WPF**

```
    private void server_outputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
                {
                     addConsoleMessage(e.Data.ToString(), true);
                });
    }
```

**Update**

In WinForms the `Invoke/BeginInvoke` methods are directly on the control objects as you can see from the docs of [System.Windows.Forms.Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.aspx). So you'd have listBox1.BeginInvoke(...) for example.

Comment: The type or namespace name 'Threading' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Windows' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: This appears to answer a question targeting WPF, but the OP is using WinForm `public partial class Form1 : Form`.