# C# System.Windows.Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms

I was programming a "Minecraft" server manager program, but i don't know why, System.Windows.Threading doesn't exist (Visual C# says that), and in here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.threading.dispatcher, it says it should exist. Please help! (Message boxes are in Polish, becouse im from Poland, later i will add multi language support)

My code:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Windows.Threading;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public Process server;

        private Boolean runServer()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(textBox2.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Brak określonej ścieżki dostępu! (" + textBox2.Text + ")", "Błąd", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
            }

            Process process = new Process
            {
                StartInfo =
                {
                    FileName = textBox2.Text,
                    //Arguments = textBox3.Text,
                    UseShellExecute = false,
                    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
                    CreateNoWindow = false,
                }
            };

            process.OutputDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(server_outputDataReceived);
            process.ErrorDataReceived += new DataReceivedEventHandler(server_outputDataReceived);
            server = process;

            if (process.Start())
                return true;
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Nie można włączyć serwera!", "Błąd", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                return false;
            }
        }

        private String ReadFile(String filename, int line)
        {
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filename);

            for (int i = 0; i < line; i++)
            {
                reader.ReadLine();
            }

            return reader.ReadLine();
        }

        private void ReloadOPs()
        {
            if (!File.Exists(textBox1.Text))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Sciezka dostępu do pliku z listą graczy posiadających OP nie istnieje! (" + textBox1.Text + ")", "Błąd", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Exclamation);
                tabControl1.SelectedTab = tabPageOptions;
                textBox1.SelectAll();
                return;
            }

            String line = ReadFile(textBox1.Text, 0);
            comboBox1.Items.Clear();
            for (int i = 1; i < File.ReadAllLines(textBox1.Text).Length; i++)
            {
                if (!String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(ReadFile(textBox1.Text, i)))
                {
                    comboBox1.Items.Add(line);
                    line = ReadFile(textBox1.Text, i);
                }
            }

            MessageBox.Show("Lista graczy z OP, została odświeżona.");
        }

        // OPs combobox (OPs)
        private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            groupBox1.Text = comboBox1.SelectedItem.ToString();
            groupBox1.Visible = true;
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = Application.StartupPath.ToString() + @"\ops.txt";
            ReloadOPs();
        }

        // Reload OPs button (OPs)
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReloadOPs();
        }


        // Save button (Options)
        private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void server_outputDataReceived(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Normal, () =>
            {
                addConsoleMessage(e.Data.ToString(), true);
            });
        }

        // Run server button (Menu)
        private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!runServer())
                return;

            server.BeginOutputReadLine();
            button6.Enabled = true;
        }

        // Stop server button (Menu)
        private void button6_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if(!server.HasExited)
                server.Kill();
            button6.Enabled = false;
        }

        private void addConsoleMessage(String message, Boolean refresh)
        {   
            listBox1.Items.Add(message);
            if (refresh)
                listBox1.Refresh();
        }
    }
}
```

My error code: Cannot convert lambda expression to type 'System.Delegate' because it is not a delegate type (server_outputDataReceived)

Comment: As a note, not all namespaces are referenced by default. When you look at the documentation, make sure to look at the "assembly": `Assembly:  WindowsBase (in WindowsBase.dll)`. If that is not already referenced in your project, you need to add a reference.

Comment: sounds like someone griefed your namespaces

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are targeting WinForm application and you are trying to use threading from WPF.

[System.Windows.Threading Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Contains types to support the Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF)
>   threading system

You should use: [System.Threading Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.aspx). You may also see [Threading in Windows Forms by Jon Skeet](http://www.yoda.arachsys.com/csharp/threads/winforms.shtml)

Comment: @user3533380, why do you need [`Dispatcher`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.threading.dispatcher) it is again used with WPF. You should look at Control.BeginInvoke,

Comment: Becouse: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23083570/c-sharp-batch-file-output-problems

Comment: @user3533380, that is not a correct answer, which you have accepted. You don't need to use Disptacher.Invoke, Look at [Control.Invoke](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.invoke(v=vs.110).aspx) and use it like `this.Invoke(...` on the current form.

Comment: I used:
this.Invoke(listBox1.Items.Add, new Object[] { e.Data.ToString() });
But I've got 2 errors:
Error 1 The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(System.Delegate, params object[])' has some invalid arguments 
Error 2 Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Delegate'

Comment: @user3533380, you need to call it like:             `this.Invoke((Action)delegate() { listBox1.Items.AddRange(new object[] {e.Data.ToString()}); });`